# 0.9% Saline or Ringer's Solution for in vivo work

Tags: animal-models, surgery, salt

A few of the labs where I currently work routinely use 0.9% saline for in vivo work (washing out debris during surgery, diluting substances for IP/IV/SC injections, etc.)

A few years ago I worked in a lab where the standard was to use Ringer's Solution. Obviously, in both labs the choice was based on an organizatorical/historical reasons. But I was wondering: Does either of these solutions perform any "better" (i.e. causes less physiological disturbances) than the other?

My guess would be Ringer's is better, since it is also suitable for keeping cells alive in vitro - and there is also [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18313809) that calls 0.9% Saline into question altogether. But I could not really find any good comparison tests.

Comment: saline versus lactated Ringer's is still a matter of preference - but I agree with you that Ringer's is better - pH and electrolyte composition are more closer to physiologic values, while saline is pH of 5.5 and slightly hyperosmolar compared to plasma.